# Burninate [pages] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[pages](/questions/tagged/pages) has 4 followers and 198 questions tagged, of course no wiki. 
The question are usually from low rep users meaning they have less experience in which tag to choose 
The questions read like this:

- [insert formatted page numbers in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383676/insert-formatted-page-numbers-in-ms-word)
- [FB app to create events
  for a page, spamming page fan's feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301562/fb-app-to-create-events-for-a-page-spamming-page-fans-feeds)
- [htaccess redirects the domain but not individual pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352357/htaccess-redirects-the-domain-but-not-individual-pages)
- [check on which pages an image is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162985/check-on-which-pages-an-image-is-used)

They have nothing in common apart for the word pages used in the question and it really doesn't help filter or add more information

Comment: I've alreay started

Comment: Dude, you've only cleared 38 tags?  Come on!!!

Comment: I tried telling my fiance I have this big job to do, She didn't buy it :(

Comment: @casperOne status-complete it?

Comment: It still exists, 41 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, it looks like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be burninated because [pages](/questions/tagged/pages) can't work as the only tag on a question, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141738/automatically-making-new-views-depending-on-array-size-new-pages.

However, when you are manually removing such tags from posts then please make sure to fix the complete question and not just remove the tag, such as [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2448222). Similarly, if you just remove the tag then some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141738/automatically-making-new-views-depending-on-array-size-new-pages) would be left untagged (which is not encouraged). Some of the questions may be tagged under [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination) too.

Why? Because the goal should be to have a cleaner and targeted Q&A site and not to take revenge on the particular misplaced/misused tag.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Sucess no PAGES!]

### They are all gone now